# How to find the xpath to a specific element buried in an array, where the unique ID is dynamic?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've been struggling with finding the xpath to:

```
div class='text-title tile-text-desc'>"Text here" /div

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//vue-kit.strand[@qa-id='MAIN_MENU_FEATURED']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='ember-view scroller']/ui-kit.collection-view.item-view[@class='ember-view item-view tile is-first is-program focus']"));
```

I have also tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//vue-kit.strand[@qa-id='MAIN_MENU_FEATURED']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='ember-view scroller']/ui-kit.collection-view.item-view[@class='ember-view item-view tile is-first is-program focus']/div[@class='meta']/div[@class='text-title tile-text-desc']"));
```

I can access `@class='ember-view item-view tile is-first is-program focus'` which returns an array. Then I can access the elements in the array with webElement and findElements. From here I'm not sure how to get the exact element that I want.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please post more relevant HTML codes. When you can't identify element by itself (i.e by the element id), try to identify by the surrounding elements (parent and/or sibling elements, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the HTML tag edit, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative path and xpath functions to get the dynamic id

Since @Class has "text-title tile-text-desc" so you can try as below:
`//div[contains(@class,'text-title tile-text-desc')]`